# I want to loop through my array and calculate my values-JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, cart

I want to able to loop my arrays and calculate the total price and display it in the console.
this is suppose to be a cart application. I assign all the anchor tags to cart variable that loops through the anchors tag and assign the the tags to the values in my beverages array to be able to display it but i cant display the total amount of all the prices.

**html**

```
<section id="menu">
    <h2>Menu</h2>
    <p>Click an item to add it to your order.</p>
    <ul class="coffeeMenu">
        <li><a id="espresso" class="add-to-cart" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a id="latte" class="add-to-cart" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a id="cappuccino" class="add-to-cart" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a id="coffee" class="add-to-cart" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a id="biscotti" class="add-to-cart" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a id="scone" class="add-to-cart " href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

**javascript**

```
  let cart = document.querySelectorAll('.add-to-cart');

  let beverages = [{
    name: 'espresso',
    price: 1.95,
    inCart: 0,
},
{
    name: 'latte',
    price: 2.95,
    inCart: 0,
},
{
    name: 'cappuccino',
    price: 3.45,
    inCart: 0,
},
{
    name: 'coffee',
    price: 1.75,
    inCart: 0,
},
{
    name: 'biscotti',
    price: 1.95,
    inCart: 0,
},
{
    name: 'scone',
    price: 2.95,
    inCart: 0,
},
   //run a loop to through the images and the array
 for (let i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
cart[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    cartNumber(beverages[i]);
    // totalCost(beverages[i]);
    })
  }



   // display the prices in the textarea

 let cartNumber = (beverages) => {
document.getElementById("order").textContent += beverages.name + " = "+ beverages.price 
    +"\n"
let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumber')
productNumbers = parseInt(productNumbers);
if (productNumbers) {
    localStorage.setItem('cartNumber', productNumbers + 1);
    document.getElementById("total").textContent
} else {
    localStorage.setItem("cartNumber", 1);
    document.getElementById('tot').textContent = 1;

   for (let i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
    cart[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    for(var price in beverages ) {
        console.log(price, beverages["prices"])
    }
})
   }

      console.log(beverages["price"]);

    let totalCost = (beverages) => {
        let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');
        console.log(cartCost)
        if(cartCost != null) {
            cartCost = parseInt(cartCost);
            localStorage.setItem("totalCost", cartCost + beverages.price)
            document.getElementById("total").textContent = "$" + cartCost ;
            document.getElementById("cartTotal").textContent = cartCost;
    
    
            
        } else {
        localStorage.setItem("totalCost",  beverages.price)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey man why are you doing too much scripting ... And also I want to know how are going to add it cart ( in beverage object ) or what ?

Comment: it gets added by looping through the cart variable and beverages array and changing the text content of the (textcontent i havent made yet) to the array values... im just trying to console log for now

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing too much and looping  .... See this , it might help you build what you are willing too

HTML

```
<section id="menu">
  <h2>Menu</h2>
  <p>
    Click an item to add it to your order.
  </p>
  <ul class="coffeeMenu">
    <li><a onclick="add_to_cart('espresso')" class="add-to-cart">espresso</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="add_to_cart('latte')" id="latte" class="add-to-cart">latte</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="add_to_cart('cappuccino')" id="cappuccino" class="add-to-cart">cappuccino</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="add_to_cart('coffee')" id="coffee" class="add-to-cart">coffee</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="add_to_cart('biscotti')" id="biscotti" class="add-to-cart">biscotti</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="add_to_cart('scone')" class="add-to-cart ">scone</a></li>
  </ul>
  <button id="total" onclick="cart_total()">Total</button>
</section>
```

JS

```
  let beverages = [{
    name: 'espresso',
    price: 1.95
  },
    {
      name: 'latte',
      price: 2.95
    },
    {
      name: 'cappuccino',
      price: 3.45
    },
    {
      name: 'coffee',
      price: 1.75
    },
    {
      name: 'biscotti',
      price: 1.95
    },
    {
      name: 'scone',
      price: 2.95
    }]

  let cart = [];
  let sum = 0;


  function add_to_cart(item) {
    let qty = prompt('Please enter quantity ')
    qty = parseInt(qty);
    if (isNaN(qty)) {
      qty = 1
    }
    cart.push({
      name: item,
      quantity: qty
    });
  }

  function cart_total() {
    console.log(cart)
    cart.forEach(item => {
      beverages.forEach(beverage => {
        if (beverage.name === item.name) {
          sum += beverage.price * item.quantity
        }
      })
    });
    console.log(sum)
  }
```

Comment: @ericstlouis I also added a prompt which will help user to  enter quantity you can do something else ... Like taking input field !

Comment: thank you for revising my code its look and is way more functional tham before

Comment: @ericstlouis that was fast  I thought u might have more doubts

Comment: @ericstlouis Your welcome happy to help !